# how to get dynamic created td value in Spring controller without using input tag

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, html-table

I am working on my current project module that is excel sheet modification by user, and I am stuck on getting Dynamic `<td>` value.

**MY JSP:**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ page session="true"%>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="save" method="post" id="exceldata">
        <table border="5" id="dataTable">
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach var="data" items="${Hello.userlist}" varStatus="loop">
                    <tr>
                        <c:forEach var="innerData" items="${data}">
                            <td id="innerData" contenteditable="true">
                            <c:out value="${innerData}"></c:out></td>
                          // ${innerData} will be updated by user
                           //here i need updated td ${innerData} data
                           //i have done all the possible R&D in 2days
                           // i can not use <input> under <td>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" value="${sizeOfData}" name="sizeOfData">
        <input type="submit" value="save">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**my controller:**

here in the my controller class and in the saveExcel i need the updated td value td

```
Excel_Data ed = new Excel_Data();

@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView showExcel() {
    List ll = ed.readData(FILE_NAME);

    lb.setUserlist(ll);
    home.addObject("sizeOfData", ll.size());
    home.addObject("Hello", lb);
    return home;
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveExcel(@ModelAttribute("userForm") ListBean lb) throws IOException {
     // what to do here?
}
}
```

I have used
`<input type="hidden" value=${innerData} name="innerData">`
but its not sending updated data

Comment: thnks @nnnnnn for formatting code

Comment: It seems like a good job for JavaScript

Comment: have you tried <input type="hidden" value=${innerData} name=${innerData} >

Comment: how to get "name=${innerData}"' in spring controller??? haven't use dynamic name but i have tried <input type="hidden" value=${innerData} name="myData" >

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, it seems like you are trying to build Excel like functionality. More than one cell can be modified and modifications need to be submitted back to server.

When form is posted, you can iterate through all the cells using javascript and build a json object. For example following sudo code

```
var cells = new Object();
for every cell
   celss[cell id] = <text content of the cell>
end for

var cellText = JSON.stringify(cells)
set the value of hidden field
```

On server side, your method needs to have expected input field using @RequestParam annotation. You can gson or such tools to parse the data. If you follow good id convention e.g. id can be "id__", you can parse it to figure out where the contents go.

Comment: thanks its good and well i was sending data through ajax but each and every row coming randomly not in sequence but  JSON.stringify(cells) will work nice work bro

Answer (score 0):

The form should be mentioned with modelAttribute, which stores the values of form into that object once after it is saved.

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<form:form method="POST" id="form" name="form" class="form"
  action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home/page2/submit"
  modelAttribute="data">  
    <table border="5" id="dataTable">
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach var="data" items="${Hello.userlist}" varStatus="loop">
                    <tr>
                        <c:forEach var="innerData" items="${data}">
                            <td id="innerData" contenteditable="true" path="name">
                            <c:out value="${innerData}"></c:out></td>
                         
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
       <input type="hidden" value="${sizeOfData}" name="sizeOfData" path="name">
        <input type="submit" value="save">
  
</form:form>
```

A class should be created as following in model package of the project

```
public class Data {
String name;
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}}
```

Controller will have the following methods, @RequestMapping(value="/method2/submit",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String method3(ModelMap model,HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request) {

```
    model.addAttribute("data",new Data());
    return VIEWS_LOCATION +"/secondPage";
}
@RequestMapping(value="/method2/submit",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String method3(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("data") Data data) {
    model.addAttribute("name",data.getName());

    return VIEWS_LOCATION +"/secondPage";
}
```

All the elements which are suffixed with path="name" will be automatically read by data model and are stored in string name.